# Merging two contour layers in QGIS changes the column heading names and creates more columns

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, merge, vector-layer

I have two contour layers that I'd like as 1. Using Vector-Data Management Tools-Merge Vector layers, I check the box next to the two contour layers, add the UTM projection I'm using, save file to folder, click OK.

My original attribute columns are: `GEO_OID`, `ELEVATION`, `CODE`, & `TILE`.
The newly merged contour layer has these Russian looking characters all starting with a `ÿ` (see screenshots), and the `TILE` column is now filled with these characters, no longer the "t123456" numbers it originally had, plus two extra columns that didn't exist before.
This is causing issues in creating the expression needed in the Field Calculator for making my index contour lines. If I create the index on the original unmerged layer, it creates the index fine, but not on the merged layer.

[image: Merged layer]

[image]

Comment: If I saw this with my layers I'd probably: 1) try to merge them in a new project, 2) try to make a copy of one and then copy and paste the other into it, 3) try the SAGA merge tool and see if it works, 4) export the inputs to another file type and try a merge to that format, and 5 open each in the Refactor Fields tool to see if any of the field attributes looked odd or conflicting.

Comment: This must be some kind of UTF-8 encoding issue. ÿþ is 00FF00FE and each column heading has the first letter of the original column heading as the 3rd character. The extra columns the tool produces are the layer and path of the original layers. What does the output of the tool say?